# How to consume TypeScript module:system export with systemjs in browser

Tags: typescript, systemjs

I’m trying to use systemjs, and I have exported this code with tsc: 
https://github.com/quantumjs/solar-popup/blob/master/package.json#L10

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "system",
    "target": "es5",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "outFile":"./build/solar-popup.js",
    "sourceRoot": "./src/SolarPopup.ts",
    "rootDir": "./src/"

  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

However then trying to consume it in the browser the imported object doesn't contain any of the exports. I think this is due to the solar-popup.js not containing any exports, just System.register calls

[image]

The export looks like this:

```
System.register("SolarPopup", ["ModalBackground", "constants"], function (exports_4, context_4) {
    "use strict";
    var __moduleName = context_4 && context_4.id;
    var ModalBackground_1, constants_2, SolarPopup;
    return {
        setters: [
            function (ModalBackground_1_1) {
                ModalBackground_1 = ModalBackground_1_1;
            },
            function (constants_2_1) {
                constants_2 = constants_2_1;
```

etc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you have these two options in `tsconfig.json`

```
"module": "system",
"outFile":"./build/solar-popup.js",
```

TypeScript generates single output file that contains several `System.register` calls, each registering a module with its own name:

```
 System.register("SolarPopup", ["ModalBackground", "constants"], function ...
```

"SolarPopup" is a module name here. SystemJS interprets such file as a [bundle, not a module](https://github.com/systemjs/builder/issues/536#issuecomment-202986021).

The result of importing a bundle is an empty object, and a side effect is that all modules inside are registered and are available immediately for importing without need to fetch them.

So you need an additional import to get a module from the bundle. Try this:

```
System.import('../build/solar-popup.js').then(function() {
    System.import('SolarPopup').then(function(SolarPopup) {
        console.dir(SolarPopup);
    });
});
```

Comment: thanks, I ended up having to do **const contactFormPopup = new SolarPopup.SolarPopup(child)** seems kinda ugly, I much prefer just using a Webpack bundle..