# How do I import and use my transpiled Typescript library using SystemJS?

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6, babeljs, systemjs

I have a TypeScript library that I've created. I need to know how to import and use this library in a browser. First, I am using tsc v2.1.4; I am also using gulp's TypeScript plugins to help with the development process. I have a gulp task that compiles my `*.ts` files to `*.js` files as follows.

```
gulp.task('dist', function() {
  var tsResult = 
    gulp.src(['src/**/*.ts'])
      .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
      .pipe(tsc({ out: 'mylib.js', noImplicitAny: true, target: 'es6', sourceMap: true, module: 'system' }));
  return tsResult.js
    .pipe(sourcemaps.write())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'));
});
```

The generated `mylib.js` file looks something like the following.

```
System.register("vehicle/car",[], function(exports_1, context_1) {
 "use strict";
 var __moduleName = context_1 && context_1.id;
 var Car;
 return {
  execute: function() {
   Car = class Car {
    constructor(make, model) {
     this.make = make;
     this.model = model;
    }
   };
   exports_1("Car", Car);
 };
});
```

I then attempt to follow the documentation on [SystemJS](https://github.com/systemjs/systemjs) and create a `index.html` to test usage.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Test MyLib</title>
  </head>
  <body onload="start()">
    <script src="node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.js"></script>
    <script>
      function start() {
        SystemJS.import('dist/mylib.js')
          .then(function(lib) {
            console.log(lib);
            //what do i do here? how do i use my classes/objects here?
          });
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Looking at the JavaScript console, I see no errors. Where I log the `lib` out, it is just an `Object` with a bunch of functions that I'm not sure how to use to instantiate the classes/objects from my library.

I'm continuing to read more on how this TypeScript to ES6 to ES5 stuff works. Apparently, even though I've generated a JavaScript file (e.g. `mylib.js`) I just can't simply reference it like

- `<script src="dist/mylib.js"></script>"`

and then use it. I have to go through `SystemJS` (which I'm new to and is a part of the confusion). Apparently, it seems like I can just reference my `*.ts` files directly and use other plugins (babel) with SystemJS to transpile on the fly. It doesn't help that the documentation on [babel systemjs plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-plugin-systemjs) is out of date (the usage instructions is out of date it seems).

The SystemJS usage instructions are a bit confusing too. In some cases I see `SystemJS.config({...})` and in some cases I see `System.config({...})`. I'm speculating they changed `SystemJS` from `System`, but I'm really not sure.

I'd appreciate clarification on how to go from a TypeScript library project all the way browser usage; any online examples or guidance on here is appreciated (and I'm continuing to search as well).

Comment: try replacing your comment with `SystemJS.import('vehicle/car').then(function(carModule) { var car = new carModule.Car('make', 'model') })`. See also http://stackoverflow.com/a/41173349/43848. With your gulp task, you shouldn't need to transpile anything in the browser, and you shouldn't need any systemjs plugins.

Comment: Thanks that helped. In that other post, there is a response about `webpack bundle`. Is that a better way to go than with this `SystemJS` approach? If I reference simple modules, no error happens, but some of my modules reference `lodash`. Any idea on how to deal with this mess? The code you show definitely works, but it reminds me of callback hell, and is something I want to avoid. If there's a better way of just getting typescript code to the browser (without nested calls, or just as simple as a one-line import, not unlike the script tags), I'd rather much prefer that route.

Comment: Well there is no way to use modules in the browser without callbacks (promises actually), at least until [<script type="module">](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1240072) is natively supported. The best way to organize an app in my opinion is to have everything in the modules, and have 1 line in the browser calling initialization/startup function. No idea about `lodash`, but you can try `SystemJS.config({map:{'lodash': 'node_modules/lodash'}, packages: {'lodash': {main:'index.js'}}})` as in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37251873/43848).

Comment: @artem Those are the accepted answers. Please post an answer and I will accept. It seems like this question is a duplicate, however, based on the reference SO post you provided.